# Python - For each number, have a list of all numbers that are one level greater

Tags: python

For each number, have a list of all numbers that are one level greater (child).

For example, the level = 1 part: 000-123-1112 (parent) 000-123-1113 (child) 000-123-1119 (child) 000-123-1120 (child)

Data:

```
# level,Number
# 0,000-123-1111
# 1,000-123-1112
# 2,000-123-1113
# 3,000-123-1114
# 4,000-123-1115
# 3,000-123-1116 -> It's not a child of line 20, it's a child of line 18
# 4,000-123-1117
# 3,000-123-1118 -> It's a child of line 17
# 2,000-123-1119 -> It's a child of line 16
# 2,000-123-1120
# 1,000-123-1121 -> It's a child of line 15
# 1,000-123-1115
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
d = {}
level_list = []

def build_dictionary(data):
    for level, number in data:
        level_list.append(level)
        d = {level: [x[1] for x in data if int(x[0]) > int(level)] for key in data}
        print(d)
```

Running the program, this is what I get, which is wrong, because when the level "resets" the program does not recognize it. Any help is appreciated...

```
{'0': ['000-123-1112', '000-123-1113', '000-123-1114', '000-123-1115', '000-123-1116', '000-123-1117', '000-123-1118', '0
00-123-1119', '000-123-1120', '000-123-1121', '000-123-1115']}
{'1': ['000-123-1113', '000-123-1114', '000-123-1115', '000-123-1116', '000-123-1117', '000-123-1118', '000-123-1119', '0
00-123-1120']}
{'2': ['000-123-1114', '000-123-1115', '000-123-1116', '000-123-1117', '000-123-1118']}
{'3': ['000-123-1115', '000-123-1117']}
{'4': []}
{'3': ['000-123-1115', '000-123-1117']}
{'4': []}
{'3': ['000-123-1115', '000-123-1117']}
{'2': ['000-123-1114', '000-123-1115', '000-123-1116', '000-123-1117', '000-123-1118']}
{'2': ['000-123-1114', '000-123-1115', '000-123-1116', '000-123-1117', '000-123-1118']}
{'1': ['000-123-1113', '000-123-1114', '000-123-1115', '000-123-1116', '000-123-1117', '000-123-1118', '000-123-1119', '0
00-123-1120']}
{'1': ['000-123-1113', '000-123-1114', '000-123-1115', '000-123-1116', '000-123-1117', '000-123-1118', '000-123-1119', '0
00-123-1120']}
```

Comment: The line numbers in your comments do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I think this is what you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [(0,"000-123-1111"),
        (1,"000-123-1112"),
        (2,"000-123-1113"),
        (3,"000-123-1114"),
        (4,"000-123-1115"),
        (3,"000-123-1116"),
        (4,"000-123-1117"),
        (3,"000-123-1118"),
        (2,"000-123-1119"),
        (2,"000-123-1120"),
        (1,"000-123-1121"),
        (1,"000-123-1115")]

d = defaultdict(list)

for level, number in data:
    for level2, number2 in data:
        if level - level2 == -1 and number2 not in d[level]:
            d[level].append(number2)

for key, value in d.items():
    print("Key: {}, Values: {}".format(key, sorted(value)))
```

Output:

```
Key: 0, Values: ['000-123-1112', '000-123-1115', '000-123-1121']
Key: 1, Values: ['000-123-1113', '000-123-1119', '000-123-1120']
Key: 2, Values: ['000-123-1114', '000-123-1116', '000-123-1118']
Key: 3, Values: ['000-123-1115', '000-123-1117']
```